# MapView shows empty in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, api, dictionary, android-mapview

I have use MapFragment in Google Maps Android API v2 . It work fine .

But when I use MapView . It display blank . I don't know what happen .

MyActivity

```
package com.example.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your layout/main.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Did you figure it out? Have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean empty? If you're getting a blank map with just the empty grid, usually this means your API key is wrong. Did you switch computers or start signing your application with a new keystore without getting a new api key?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview

> Users of this class must forward all the Activity life cycle methods - such as onCreate(), onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause() - to the corresponding methods in the MapView class.

You need to forward those calls so the view gets a chance to render the map.